# I'd like to ask help on how to custom format the specific number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I'd like to custom format 20001.10.19 to 01/10/19/. 
I have tried many things, but nothing has worked.. I'm using Microsoft Excel 2007.

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,4,99),".","/")`

Comment: how is `20001.10.19` derived? and what is `01/10/19/` meant to represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value is stored as a date, you can use normal custom formatting settings:

Format the cell, choose custom and then enter the Type manually as: `yy/mm/dd/`

[image]